# Slice variable from specified letter to specified letter in line that varies in length

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to the site so I apologize if I format this incorrectly.

So I'm searching a file for lines containing

`Server[x] ip.ip.ip.ip response=235ms accepted....`

where x can be any number greater than or equal to 0, then storing that information in a variable named `line`.

I'm then printing this content to a `tkinter` GUI and its way too much information for the window.

To resolve this I thought I would slice the information down with a `return line[15:30]` in the function but the info that I want off these lines does not always fall between 15 and 30.

To resolve this I tried to make a loop with

`return line[cnt1:cnt2]`

checked `cnt1` and `cnt2` in a loop until `cnt1` meets "S" and `cnt2` meets "a" from accepted.

The problem is that I'm new to Python and I cant get the loop to work.

```
def serverlist(count):
    try:
        with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
            searchlines = f.readlines()
        if 'f' in locals():
            for i, line in enumerate(reversed(searchlines)):
                cnt = 90
                if "Server["+str(count)+"]" in line:
                    if line[cnt] == "t":
                        cnt += 1
                    return line[29:cnt]
    except WindowsError as fileerror:
        print(fileerror)
```

I did a `reversed` on the line reading because the lines I am looking for repeats over and over every couple of minutes in the text file.

Originally I wanted to scan from the bottom and stop when it got to `server[0]` but this loop wasn't working for me either.

I gave up and started just running `serverlist(count)` and specifying the server number I was looking for instead of just running `serverlist()`.

Hopefully when I understand the problem with my original loop I can fix this.

**End goal here**:

*file.txt* has multiple lines with

`<timestamp/date> Server[x] ip.ip.ip.ip response=<time> accepted <unneeded garbage>`

I want to cut just the `Server[x]` and the response time out of that line and show it somewhere else using a variable.

The line can range from `Server[0]` to `Server[999]` and the same response times are checked every few minutes so I need to avoid duplicates and only get the latest entries at the bottom of the log.

Im sorry this is lengthy and confusing.

---

EDIT:

Here is what I keep thinking should work but it doesn't:

```
def serverlist():
ips = []
cnt = 0
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
        while cnt >= 0:
            if "Server["+str(cnt)+"]" in line:
                ips.append(line.split()) # split on spaces
                cnt += 1
return ips
```

My test log file has server[4] through server[0]. I would think that the above would read from the bottom of the file, print server[4] line, then server[3] line, etc and stop when it hits 0. In theory this would keep it from reading every line in the file(runs faster) and it would give me only the latest data. BUT when I run this with `while cnt >=0` it gets stuck in a loop and runs forever. If I run it with any other value like 1 or 2 then it returns a blank list `[]`. I assume I am misunderstanding how this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my first approach:

```
def serverlist(count):
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if "Server[" + str(count) + "]" in line:
                return line.split()[1] # split on spaces
    return False

print serverlist(30)
# ip.ip.ip.ip

print serverlist(";-)")
# False
```

You can change the index in `line.split()[1]` to get the specific space separated string of the line.

---

**Edit**: Sure, just remove the if condition to get all ip's:

```
def serverlist():
    ips = []
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.strip().startswith("Server["):
                ips.append(line.split()[1]) # split on spaces
    return ips
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution for cutting the line down just the data that I need. I was able to change the index to 3:6 to get what I needed. Is it possible to add the loop into the function so that it gives me all results in one query? As it is this only returns the result for server[30].

Comment: That wouldn't pull only the lines with the "Server[x]" so it returns everything in the file which is too much info. 

To clarify: With the first solution in place I can run serverlist(0), then serverlist(1), then serverlist(2), etc to get the values that I want but this is alot of typing if I have 99 servers. I'd like to just run serverlist() and it output to my GUI the info from each server but only one time and only the entries from the bottom of the file so I know they are the latest info.

Comment: I edited it again. Are the numbers unique in the file?

Comment: That was putting nothing into the list. I did it like this:

'def serverlist():
    ips = []
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if "Server[" in line:
                ips.append(line.split()[3:6]) # split on spaces
    return ips
'

This gives me each item but since the lines repeat through the log it will show 40 results for server[1]. I need to make it stop when it gets to the first server[0] when searching from the bottom. This way it just gets the latest check on response times.

Comment: how do I show the above code where it doesn't look all jumbled?